# Trouble with ParametricPlot and custom options

Tags: plotting, options

Consider the following code:

```
Options[pl] = {lim->{0,1}};
pl[n_, OptionsPattern[]] := Plot[x^n, Join[{x}, OptionValue[lim]] ]
```

This function works as expected on 12.0: running something like `pl[2]` produces a plot over $[0,1]$, while `pl[2, lim->{2,3}]` uses the given limits.

But if I instead use `ParametricPlot`, as in

```
Options[pl] = {lim->{0,1}};
pl[n_, OptionsPattern[]] := ParametricPlot[{x,x^n}, Join[{x}, OptionValue[lim]] ]
```

then `pl[2]` just gives

```
System`SampledPlotsDump`iParametricPlot[{x, x^2}, Join[{x}, OptionValue[pl, {}, lim]]]
```

with a similar error message when explicitly including the option. What could be going on here? Why does `ParametricPlot` behave differently from `Plot`?

Comment: replace `Join[{x}, OptionValue[lim]]`with `Evaluate@Join[{x}, OptionValue[lim]]`?

Comment: @kglr That sure worked, thanks! But do you have any idea why that has to be done, and why the problem only happens with ParametricPlot?

Comment: Javier, don't know why `Plot` and `ParametricPlot` behave differently.